# Como serializar object para yaml em .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, serialização, yaml

Podemos serializar objetos (vou usar como exemplo `C#`)  para `XML`, usando a classe `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`, por exemplo:

```
var obj = new AlgumaClasse();

System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
var xmlString = writer.ToString();
```

Ou para `json` usando por exemplo o package `Newtonsoft`, com o classe `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject`:

```
var obj = new AlgumaClasse();
var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

A minha pergunta é: como serializar um objeto para o formato `yaml`?

Existe alguma classe ou package que faça isso de forma semalhante aos exemplos acima?

Comment: deu certo?.....

Comment: sim, usei o "YamlDotNet.NetCore" e atendeu bem, obrigado :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe pacotes que podem resolver o seu problema:

- [YamlDotNet.NetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/YamlDotNet.NetCore/)

Classe Base:

```
public class ExampleObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Example
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Version { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Sources { get; set; }
    public ExampleObject ExampleObject { get; set; }
}
```

Como usar?

```
Example example = new Example();
example.Id = 1;
example.Version = Guid.NewGuid();
example.Name = "Example";
example.Sources = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>
{
    "1",
    "2"
};
example.ExampleObject = new ExampleObject
{
    Id = 2,
    Name = "Object"
};

var serializer = new SerializerBuilder().Build();
var yaml = serializer.Serialize(example);
```

Resultado:

```
Id: 1
Version: 310bf8c6-87e1-4ea0-84d7-25c615d5d4b8
Name: Example
Sources:
- 1
- 2
ExampleObject:
  Id: 2
  Name: Object
```

[Github: YamlDotNet/wiki](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/wiki)

[Using custom type converters with C# and YamlDotNet, part 1](https://www.cyotek.com/blog/using-custom-type-converters-with-csharp-and-yamldotnet-part-1)

---

Outro pacote interessante:

- [SharpYaml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpYaml/)

Como utilizar?

```
var serializer = new SharpYaml.Serialization.Serializer();
var yaml = serializer.Serialize(example);
```

Resultado:

```
!ConsoleApp1.Example,%2520ConsoleApp1,%2520Version=1.0.0.0,%2520Culture=neutral,%2520PublicKeyToken=null
ExampleObject:
  Id: 2
  Name: Object
Id: 1
Name: Example
Sources:
  - 1
  - 2
Version: 38d0a3a1-c963-4805-86fc-6bcb838d23d7
```

[Github: SharpYaml](https://github.com/xoofx/SharpYaml)